# How do i able to post all of my checked values from my radio buttons through an ajax xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Scenario: I have a 4 input forms [A-D] then i have checked the A and B.

i want to get it from the other page but i don't know how.. i was trying to search for other people post to learn but there is much a lot of tutorials about ajax is on posting select and input tags.

can you please give me an example about radio buttons
when i'm going to checked the value i want and to submit it clicking the button
to send an ajax xmlhttpequest to other script.

thank you in advance dude :)
[image]

i'm using jQuery to post the value of the option tag i have selected
then it will call back to the div to show a table with a list of radio buttons

i have already tried to get the data by pushing all the values of checked data into a set of strings of an array by using jQuery and it was successful :)

but it doesn't response to the other page (Admin) what user have submitted.
and that's why i need to refresh it to load and see what the data had user  submitted. (different user/session).

i was wondering if i could use xml httprequest to do a real time interaction with the user-admin.

that's why i was hoping if anyone could give me an example how to get the values of radio buttons i have checked to post it to the other script and insert in the db.

[image]

sir.

Comment: Do you want to have the form data appear on another page, another place on the same page, or do you want to send the data to your server?

Comment: i want to save data to the db sir. then in the other page i want get the data i save from the db by using xmlhttprequest. but i don't know how to get the  values of checked radio button and to send it also by using the same ajax function

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: i was using jquery to dropdown a list of radio buttons from the other script sir. then i was wondering to use xmlhttprequest to trigger the 'admin page' lets say to get the values checked by the user.

Comment: is it ok to use jQuery and xmlhttprequest inside the script tag?

Comment: Yes - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initial page, you can use this:

```
$.ajax('/WHERE_DATA_IS_SENT', {
    data: $('input[name=name_of_your_radiobutton]:checked').val(),
    success: function (data) {
         // Do something... maybe redirect the user to the other page?
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Data could not be sent to the server');
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Then in the other page, you can use jQuery `ajax` again to get the data from the server:

```
$.ajax('/WHERE_YOU_GET_THE_DATA', {
    success: function (data) {
        $('ELEMENT_WHERE_DATA_GOES').html(data)
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Data could not be received from the server');
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: i'm using a xml httprequest to post data to the other page sir but i dont know how to get all the values i have checked in the initial page.

Comment: At the top, I use `$('input[name=name_of_your_radiobutton]:checked').val()` Use this.

Comment: can i convert that script like var x = getelementsbyclassname('name_buttons'). correct me if i'm wrong sir :) if (getelementsbyclassname('name_buttons').checked)

Comment: i have updated my question above sir :) please see thanks

Comment: Reading your edits, do you want to have server-side push to the Admin console?

Comment: exactly sir :) . coz i want to get what the user had submitted i'm gonna using it to trigger the admin_page function script to refresh the data what user had submitted.

Comment: To do server-side push like that, you probably want to learn about [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Otherwise, you would have to use JS to continually ping the server for changes, which is slow, unreliable, and uses up all your bandwidth.

Comment: can i set time interval for the script to reload again sir without clicking any buttons?

Comment: Yes, you could. Use `setInterval(function(){AJAX_REQUEST_HERE}, INTERVAL_TIME_IN_MS)`